# How to embed camera in Xamarin form and take image with custom button click?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-forms-4

[image: Prototype of app]

So as you can see in the above image I have an requirement to embed camera in Xamarin form based android application (Not native android) and show the saved path in label (Storage location).

Right now I am able to do is on button click but its opening the camera and from there when i take image its navigating back to the app but my requirement is that camera should open within the app it self instead of navigation.

I have gone through with **Xamarin.Forms Custom Renderers** but so far not found any working code.

It will be great if anybody can provide me the same ..looking forward...

Comment: We could create a  Xamarin.Forms page that will serve as our point of interaction with the custom code . Check https://thatcsharpguy.github.io/post/full-camera-page.1/

Comment: This implementation navigates me from one page to another page but I want to do all without any navigation can you help me here?

Comment: Many thanks for sharing this link. I did some changes in the existing project and its working fine as expected.

Comment: You could share your answer,which will help more people

Comment: @JARVIS can you share your work, i also want to implement the same functionality.